# How to Set Proxy URL in ionic.config.json

Tags: angular, proxy, ionic4

I am having an issue with Ionic 4 when attempting to make GET calls to an API. I am using Ionic local server, running ionic serve in the command line for live server.

ionic.config.json

```
{
 "name": "myApp",
  "type": "angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/apii",
      "proxyUrl": "https://api.promlmsoftware.com/api/user"
    }
  ]


}
```

This is my configuration in ionic.config.json
Here having any errors ?

list.page.ts

```
 let headerss = new Headers();
    headerss.append('apikey', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

    let options=new RequestOptions({headers:headerss});
    this.http.get("/apii",options).pipe(
    map(res => res.json()))
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.data = data.results;
      console.log(this.data);
    },err =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lluxX.png)
Ho can i fix this

Comment: any solution please